# Why does this PHP line of code cause a syntax error on my webhosting, but not on c9?

Tags: php, html, forms, session

It is a line of code where the text area should be blank if there is no SESSION. If there is a SESSION, put the contents into the textarea. Is there really an error here, or is it just the webhosting's problem?

```
<form id="translateform" action="processTranslation.php" method="post"><?php 
echo "<textarea maxlength='3000' id='inputField' placeholder='Enter your Lorem Ipsum text here:' name='translate'>";
if(isset($_SESSION['text'])){
    echo $_SESSION['text'];
    }
    echo "</textarea>";
        ?>
```

Error message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier". Here is almost the entire code:

```
<form id="translateform" action="process.php" method="post"><?php 
if(!empty($_SESSION['text'])){
    echo "<textarea maxlength='3000' id='inputField' placeholder='Enter your Lorem Ipsum text here:' name='translate'>" . $_SESSION['text'] . "</textarea>";
    }
   else{
echo "<textarea maxlength='3000' id='inputField' placeholder='Enter your Lorem Ipsum text here:' name='translate'></textarea>";
}
        ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
<a href="projects.html"><div id="back"><p id="goback">Back!</p></div></a>
<script>
if(document.referrer=="msolonko.net16.net/projects.html"){
document.cookie="navigatedFromSite=agreed";
}
else if(document.referrer!="msolonko.net16.net/projects.html"&&document.referrer!="msolonko.net16.net/LoremIpsum.php"){
 document.cookie = "navigatedFromSite="no";
}
var x=document.cookie;
if(x.search("navigatedFromSite")!=-1&&x.search("agreed")!=-1){
 document.getElementById("back").style.display="initial";
}
</script>
<?php
echo "<div id='containertranslation'><p id='translation'>";
if(isset($_SESSION['translation'])){echo $_SESSION['translation'];}//if translated
else{echo "Translation: ";}//if not, empty field
echo "</p></div>";//adds div with translation

?>
```

As you can see, I set cookie to see which page the user navigated from. If it is from the website, a back button should appear. This works in cloud9, but doesn't in this hosting. Here is the error messages: [image: errors]
This is line 109:

```
echo "<textarea maxlength='3000' id='inputField' placeholder='Enter your Lorem Ipsum text here:' name='translate'></textarea>";
```

This is line 119: 
`else if(document.referrer!="msolonko.net16.net/projects.html"&&document.referrer!="msolonko.net16.net/LoremIpsum.php"){`

Comment: Whats the error-message?

Comment: And, what version of PHP is your web-hosting service running?  I don't use PHP on my sites so I wasn't affected by this, but it is only comparatively recently that my host "upgraded" from PHP-4 to PHP-5!

Comment: Why down vote? Your problem is to check if the `$_SESSION['text']` is empty right? Its just the same as `no session`.

Comment: It wasn't my down vote. The error message is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier".

Comment: @MikeRobinson The version is PHP-5

Comment: Can you display the full code if possible? How about trying my answer.

Comment: @Zange-chan There are more than 100 lines of code. If this code works on cloud9 and I don't seem to have any errors in that statement, it is probably something wrong with the webhosting.

Comment: Just post the part of the code where the error exist, if possible, the block of code.

Comment: Yeah... I don't smell a "syntax error, unexpected identifier," *here.*  What I **do** smell is the old, too-familiar, "red herring."  I'll bet that you're being fooled, right now, as to what-and-where the actual error is.  If it IS a syntax-error, and if you're running *(or, can run)* the same PHP-version in both places, then you should be able to discover it using just your local machine.  e.g.:  `find *.php | xargs php -l` (which finds the name of all PHP-files and executes "php lint" on all of them...)

Comment: ... and if it **is**, as I now suspect, "a red herring," there lives-and-breathes not a single computer programmer who has not had his/her fill of "those damnable fish."  **;-)**  "So, you're among friends."

Comment: @Zange-chan I posted everything expect from the stylesheet. Another functionality does not work in my code which worked in cloud9. Maybe it is all the same issue.

Comment: Which line does the error point?

Comment: @Zange-chan I added a picture of the errors a well as the 2 lines it is pointing to.

Comment: @NickSolonko
Click the error to display the line. And its not the php that gives the error, its the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty($_SESSION)` instead of `isset($_SESSION)` to check if the `$_SESSION` variable is empty or not.

```
 // checks if the variable is empty or not
 if (!empty($_SESSION['text'])) {
     // display inside <textarea>
     echo "<textarea>" . $_SESSION['text'] . "</textarea>";
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code. I don't see why mine is any different, but I get the same error. The weird thing is that cloud9 doesn't give me any errors in the console. Probably my webhosting's bad.

Comment: Naah, in this case your web-host *can't* be "bad."  Either they're running PHP-5 or they are not.   So far as I can see, *there are no* "syntax errors" in the snippet of code that you've posted here.  Step back and re-examine the situation.  You're chasing a red fish.

Comment: @MikeRobinson
Sharp eyes is needed for every programmer. *thumbs up*